# Мини-планкер с одной html

Tags: javascript, html, angular2

Использую `Angular 2` + `bootstrap`. Мне необходимо сделать страницу на которой будет окошко с `html` разметкой в виде текста (желательно с отступами и подсветкой синтаксиса) и рядом ее отображение. При изменении текста в окне с `html`, меняется и отображение. Есть ли что-нибудь 
уже готовое для этого на `angular 2` ? Какая-нибудь библиотека...

Comment: Т.е. вам нужен WYSIWYG Text Editor ? Просто вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079280/rich-text-editor-for-angularjs неплохо описаны подобные. Если неверно вас понял - то сорри

Comment: @alexoander Отлично, спасибо!

Comment: Отметил как ответ - пометьте его как правильный (если он вам помог конечно). Тогда в будущем, кому-то пригодится ваш вопрос. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.е. вам нужен WYSIWYG Text Editor ? Просто вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079280/rich-text-editor-for-angularjs) неплохо описаны подобные. И там же описаны способы их подключения.